# mysql_connect not defined

Tags: php, mysql

I'm testing a connection to mysql 5.1, with php5 on apache2 (windows).

I have made a regular php test connection page from a tutorial but I'm getting the error `"mysql_connect" not defined`.

In eclipse for php, I see the function defined under the language library.  However when I make a page:

```
<?php
 phpinfo();
?>
```

I don't see mysql functions or anything there; can someone tell me why?  I thought PHP5 at the least would support MySQL, no?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is php documentation

http://php.net/docs.php

mysql_connect

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php

however mysql extension should be enabled in php.ini

(linux: /etc/apache2/)

Answer (score 2):

The MySQL extension is probably not enabled. If you look through the php.ini file, you should be able to find the appropriate line. `phpinfo()` will show the location of the php.ini file.

Comment: the dll is enabled in php.ini file